# Is there a .NET StringBuilder that uses UTF-8 directly?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a performance sensitive scenario where I would like to write UTF-8 to a byte array.

A quick glimpse on the .NET StringBuilder class has me believe that it only builds UTF-16 natively. Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str) means extra allocations and extra clock cycles that I am not willing to spend.

Is there a native UTF-8 writer?

Comment: Are you sure this is your performance bottle-neck? Because that's hard to believe.

Comment: Yes. We're doing over 3 million http requests per second and machine using specialized network gateways.

Comment: Doesn't appear to ship with the framework or extensions, but the implementation here is informative: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/d037e070ebe5c83838443f869d5800752b0fcb13/src/coreclr/tools/Common/Internal/Text/Utf8StringBuilder.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) is like a StringBuilder for bytes; you can use it to create a sequence of bytes efficiently by repeatedly appending sequences of bytes to it. It doesn't have methods to append strings of characters though. To avoid converting each string to a byte array first, you can wrap the stream in a [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) which takes care of the conversion.

Comment: But that only does the GetBytes() in smaller pieces.

Comment: The conversion from a .NET string to UTF8 has to happen somewhere. The point is that the StreamWriter does allocate a new buffer for each conversion.

Comment: A follow up question is if there is a .NET integer to UTF-8 string converter that does not first generate a .NET string.